# Specify a calendar in a URL creating an event in Google Calendar

Tags: url, events, google-calendar-api

My Google Calendar has several calendars, say Calendar A, Calendar B, and Calendar C. I have a URL to create an event in Google Calendar, but it always gets created in my "primary" (I guess default) calendar, say Calendar B.  I want to create an event in Calendar C.  I have the Calendar ID for Calendar C for example:

lpcpgfv0ihuodhs4d62387me00@group.calendar.google.com

but don't know how to include it in the URL.  This is what I have so far:

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Appointment+with+John+Doe&dates=20190310T060000/20190310T073000&ctz=America/New_York&location=Miami&details=Meeting+with+John+Doe+lots+of+detail+here&sf=true&output=xml

Comment: Have you check if using the method [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) could help you in the function you needed?

Comment: Yes, I tried variations on Calendar ID but I think these are API concepts and not variables I can use in a URL.  Thanks though.